# alternative encoding function to base64

Tags: encoding

does anyone know a encoding/decoding function similar to base64_encode/decode, but that only outputs numbers and or letters, as base64 sometimes outputs = which is messing up my code. Thanks

Comment: I hope you're confusing encoding and encryption, because if you're actually using base64 for encryption, you're living with a false sense of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is not encryption. I'd suggest you learn aboutwhat encryption means. But anyway, it sounds like what you want is Base32 encoding. In Python, you can get it just by doing

```
base64.b32encode(data)
```

Edit: base32 encoding also uses = to pad by default, but if it is causing a problem, you can simply omit the padding.

```
base64.b32encode(data).rstrip('=')
```

Comment: i meent encoding, sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithm I created for an owncloud app I wrote. You can specify your own alphabet, so it might be worth a try. The implementation is in php but can easily be ported.

```
  /**
   * @method randomAlphabet
   * @brief Creates a random alphabet, unique but static for an installation
   * @access public
   * @author Christian Reiner
   */
  static function randomAlphabet ($length)
  {
    if ( ! is_integer($length) )
      return FALSE;
    $c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxwz0123456789";
    return substr ( str_shuffle($c), 0, $length );
  } // function randomAlphabet

  /**
   * @method OC_Shorty_Tools::convertToAlphabet
   * @brief Converts a given decimal number into an arbitrary base (alphabet)
   * @param integer number: Decimal numeric value to be converted
   * @return string: Converted value in string notation
   * @access public
   * @author Christian Reiner
   */
  static function convertToAlphabet ( $number, $alphabet )
  {
    $alphabetLen = strlen($alphabet);
    if ( is_numeric($number) )
         $decVal = $number;
    else throw new OC_Shorty_Exception ( "non numerical timestamp value: '%1'", array($number) );
    $number = FALSE;
    $nslen = 0;
    $pos = 1;
    while ($decVal > 0)
    {
      $valPerChar = pow($alphabetLen, $pos);
      $curChar = floor($decVal / $valPerChar);
      if ($curChar >= $alphabetLen)
      {
        $pos++;
      } else {
        $decVal -= ($curChar * $valPerChar);
        if ($number === FALSE)
        {
          $number = str_repeat($alphabet{1}, $pos);
          $nslen = $pos;
        }
        $number = substr($number, 0, ($nslen - $pos)) . $alphabet{(int)$curChar} . substr($number, (($nslen - $pos) + 1));
        $pos--;
      }
    }
    if ($number === FALSE) $number = $alphabet{1};
    return $number;
  }
```